# In my iOS app zh-hans.lproj does not work

Tags: ios, localization

I have Base.lproj and en.lproj and zh-hans.lproj in my project folder and use `NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle` to get the key in Localizable.strings file, everything works well in en.lproj but when I change the language to "简体中文" and change the union to China, and I rebuild the app, but the string always shows in english char. Anybody meets the similar case? Or maybe should I config something in my app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should add zh-hans in my app side which consume the library I write have been localized.